# In android, Empty activity launched while tapping mime type nfc tag, then fetched data from server?

Tags: android, nfc

In android, I wrote mime type text/plain with package name in nfc tag. When app in closed state, if I tapped, it launched the specific activity. OnResume() called and load the data from server. In this case, it shows empty activity page,(No images or labels) then server fetched the data and displayed.

Two screens shown while tapping the mime type nfc tag. I want to show the page with data retrieved from server. Please help me out for this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
 if (MyUtils.isNetworkAvailable(Details.this)) {
            homeViewModel.getList();
        } else {
            List<GetModelResponse.ListData> listData = queries.getList();
            if (listData.size() > 0) {
                String[] separated = str.split(":");

                for (int i = 0; i < listData.size(); i++) {
                    if (separated[0].equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(listData.get(i).getId()))) {
                        listData.get(i).setDate(MyUtils.getCurrentDate());
                        queries.insertPendingPay(listData.get(i));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Fetching data from server api.

Comment: post some code.. how you are fetching data

Comment: Fetching the data from server api code. fetching the data done properly but it shows unloaded activity then fetched the data from server and shown.

Comment: so you want to fetch the data, then show the activity?

Comment: If you have configured things correctly, starting the App via NFC will start the Activity in the same was as if it was started directly from a Launcher Icon and goes through the same lifecycle process. It might help if you showed your manifest file and the contents of the Activity's `onCreate` and `onResume` method.